# Greasemonkey Uncaught ReferenceError: initScript is not defined in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, cross-browser, greasemonkey

The code below, Greasemonkey script, works in Firefox and Opera. Also when packaged for Safari it works fine. When run in Chrome however I get Uncaught ReferenceError: initScript is not defined. Everything seems to work fine right up until initScript() is called. jQuery successfully loads and the setWide() and setHigh() functions work correctly.

If I move the initScript() function inside of preparePage() then it works fine. I'm not sure why that is necessary though.

I have the script wrapped in an anonymous function so I could set "use strict" once for the entire script. I have tried running the script without "use strict" and also without being wrapped. No change.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

MORE INFO: I commented out all the code within each function and just put in a console.log message at the beginning of each function.

```
function initScript() {
    console.log('initScript');
}
```

If I do that for every function then each function is run in order as it should be. I'm wondering if the way jQuery is loaded might be the issue.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Testing Userscript
// @namespace       http://www.example.com/scripts
// @description     Cross browser testing
// @include         *://apps.facebook.com/exmaple/*
// @include         *://*.example.com/platforms/facebook/game
// @exclude         *://apps.facebook.com/example/rubies
// @match           *://apps.facebook.com/example/*
// @match           *://*.example.com/platforms/facebook/game
// @include         *://plus.google.com/games/example*
// @include         *://*.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr?url=app://example*
// @match           *://plus.google.com/games/example*
// @match           *://*.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr?url=app://example*
// @require         https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
// @version         0.0.5
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function initScript() {
        var $J = jQuery.noConflict(), /* Change jQuery alias */
            OBJECT = "#swf_object", /* Page and browser specific constants */
            GLOBAL_VAR1, /* Global constants from object flashvars (see getFlashvars) */
            GLOBAL_VAR2;

        function getFlashvars() {
            var flashvars = $J(OBJECT + " param[name='flashvars']").attr("value").split("&"),
                keyValue,
                rslt = {};
            $J.each(flashvars, function () {
                keyValue = this.split("=");
                rslt[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
            });
            GLOBAL_VAR1 = rslt.global_var1;
            GLOBAL_VAR2 = rslt.global_var2;
            alert(GLOBAL_VAR1);
        }

        getFlashvars();
    }

    function preparePage() {
        var iframe,
            $J = jQuery.noConflict(),
            object = "#swf_object",
            platform;

        function setHigh() {
            clearTimeout();
            if ($J(object).length < 1) {
                setTimeout(setHigh, 100);
                return;
            }
            switch (platform) {
            case "facebook":
                $J("#hd > div").css("display", "none");
                break;
            case "google":
                $J("#pane_hd").css("display", "none");
                break;
            }
            $J("#container").width("760px");
            initScript();
        }

        function setWide() {
            clearTimeout();
            if ($J(iframe).length < 1) {
                setTimeout(setWide, 100);
                return;
            }
            switch (platform) {
            case "facebook":
                $J("#rightCol").css("display", "none");
                break;
            }
            $J(iframe).parents().width("100%");
        }

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("facebook") !== -1) {
            iframe = "#iframe_canvas";
            platform = "facebook";
        } else if (window.location.href.indexOf("google") !== -1) {
            iframe = "#oz-gadgets-canvas-iframe-example";
            platform = "google";
        }

        if (window.top === window.self) {
            setWide();
        } else {
            setHigh();
        }
    }

    function addLibrary(callback) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js");
        script.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }, false);
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
        addLibrary(preparePage);
    } else {
        preparePage();
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

> POSSIBLE SOLUTION: Removed the anonymous function. Place the initScript() and preparePage() function inside another function called main(). Change addLibrary(preparePage) to addLibrary(main). Added a call to preparePage() at the bottom of the main() function. That seems to work in Chrome. Not tested elsewhere yet. Will post the fixed code if/when I'm happy with it. Not sure if this is the best way to go yet though. Any input is always appreciated :)